# Ruby - Array of Hashes - Find value from DateTime Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, datetime, hash

I have an array of hashes saved to the database. The dates are in DateTime format.

```
@item.yearly_interest_totals = [
    {"financial_year" => "Sun, 01 Jan 2017 00:00:00 +0000", "total" => "360"},
    {"financial_year" => "Mon, 01 Jan 2018 00:00:00 +0000", "total" => "240"},
    {"financial_year" => "Tue, 01 Jan 2019 00:00:00 +0000", "total" => "240"}
]
```

In my view, I have a specific financial year in a variable financial_year

How can I display the corresponding value with the financial_year key? I'm a little confused about comparing a financial year integer to a DateTime object...

For example:

```
<tr>
         <td>Financial Year: <%= financial_year.to_i %></td>
         <td><%= @item.yearly_interest_totals.find{|i| i["financial_year"] == DateTime.new(financial_year.to_i,1,1)}["total"] %></td>
</tr>
```

This should display as:

Financial Year: 2017 360

FYI: Rails 5.0.0.1, Ruby 2.3.1, Local Postgres DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
financial_year = 2018
yearly_interest_totals.map do |t|
  t["total"] if Date.parse(t["financial_year"]).year == financial_year
end.compact
#⇒ ["240"]
```

---

```
yearly_interest_totals.detect do |t|
  Date.parse(t["financial_year"]).year == financial_year 
end["total"]
#⇒ "240"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

```
financial_year = 2017
```

then you can do:

```
@items.yearly_interest_totals.each do |yit|
  yit.merge!(DateTime.strptime(yit['financial_year'], "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z").year => yit['total'])
end
#=>[
#   {"financial_year"=>"Sun, 01 Jan 2017 00:00:00 +0000", "total"=>"360", 2017=>"360"},
#   {"financial_year"=>"Mon, 01 Jan 2018 00:00:00 +0000", "total"=>"240", 2018=>"240"},
#   {"financial_year"=>"Tue, 01 Jan 2019 00:00:00 +0000", "total"=>"240", 2019=>"240"}
# ]
```

Now in your view:

```
<tr>
  <td>Financial Year: <%= financial_year %></td>
  <td><%= @item.yearly_interest_totals.find{|yit| yit[financial_year] }[financial_year] %></td>
</tr>
```

Note that I assume that you are showing this in another loop of financial years then above solution makes the time complexity of O(n2), which is not an efficient approach, otherwise it works.

---

If we can change this array to a hash of hash then it can work much better for the large dataset:

```
yearly_interest_totals = @items.yearly_interest_totals.each_with_object({}) do |yit, obj|
  obj[DateTime.strptime(yit['financial_year'], "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z").year] = yit
end
# =>
# {
#   2017=>{"financial_year"=>"Sun, 01 Jan 2017 00:00:00 +0000", "total"=>"360"}, 
#   2018=>{"financial_year"=>"Mon, 01 Jan 2018 00:00:00 +0000", "total"=>"240"}, 
#   2019=>{"financial_year"=>"Tue, 01 Jan 2019 00:00:00 +0000", "total"=>"240"}
# }
```

Now in your view:

```
<tr>
  <td>Financial Year: <%= financial_year %></td>
  <td><%= yearly_interest_totals[financial_year]['total'] %></td>
</tr>
```

If you have multiple financial data for a year then I'd suggest you have the value of `yearly_interest_totals` hash as an array or update the total(whichever works).